# Adding a node to server's address space in OPC UA ANSI C stack

Tags: opc, ansi-c, opc-ua

I have a problem with OPC UA ANSI C stack, a very simple project for a subject: simply add a node to the server's address space, so that a client can then read it.

I know there is the open source ANSI C stack (open62541), but I need to use the official one.

I found these two objects inside the stack: the struct `OpcUa_AddNodesItem` (stackcore/opcua_types.h) and the function `OpcUa_ServerApi_AddNodes` (proxystub/serverstub/opcua_serverapi.c).

I think that this struct must be inserted inside the function, but I have some problems to set these two object's parameters.

Inside `ansicservermain.c`, how have I fill this two objects to add a node on the fly (for example, an integer variable)?

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 3):

The OPC Foundation is only releasing the OPC UA Stack in ANSI C. This only allow you to have the communication layer. To have a fully functionnal OPC UA Server you need to develop your own Server on top of it, that will manage stuff like the AddressSpace (where you have the Node), the Session, the Subscription,...
You can try and buy some OPC UA Server SDK that have everything implemented or develop you own.

If you basically want to add some Nodes with the OPC UA Stack "Demo Server" there is 2 possibilites.

- Add a static nodes by adding nodes in the addressspace_init.h files
- Implement the OpcUa_ServerApi_AddNodes() which will be called by the OPC UA AddNodes Service, allowing an OPC UA Client to add some new nodes on the fly in an OPC UA Server (there is currently not so many OPC UA Client nor Server supporting this features as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to know the steps to add and manage a node within a server's address space in ansi c. Like: addNode (), initnode (), addattribute() for example and view the update in Client.